# Delete all records from the sqlite3 database iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, sqlite, delete-row

in my application I have stored the data in my **sqlite3** database and uploading all my **sqlite3** database to my online sever, once it copied to my server, I want to delete all my records I have stored in my local database.

I have two view controller first view controller, where I store the data to **sqlite3** second view controller I have used to load the data to my server I have given like if user connected to network it has to upload the data.

I want like after uploading data to my server I want to delete all the records in my local database.

I have already tried some method its not working please tell me how to resolve this.

```
- (void) Delete_LoginData 
{
    if(sqlite3_open([self.filePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sql = "DELETE * FROM reg";
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql,-1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }
     }
}
```

I called this function in my `Reachability`.

```
- (BOOL)reachable
{
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(internetStatus == NotReachable) 
    {    
    }
    else
    {
        [self Delete_LoginData];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

My file path.

```
- (NSString *) filePath
{
    NSArray *paths = filepath, YES);

    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bp.sqlite"];
}
```

Code open the db.

```
- (void)openDB
{
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db)!=SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Database failed to open");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"database opened");
    }
}
```

I have used this above method to delete record from my local database its not working please to where I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sqlite3_step` instead of `sqlite3_reset` to execute the query

```
if(sqlite3_open([self.filePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sql = "DELETE FROM reg";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql,-1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
       if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
       // executed
       }else{
         //NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(db))
       }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
sqlite3_close(db);
```

Comment: The statement needs to be finalized and the database needs to be closed to clean everything up properly.

Comment: Yep. But thats something he must know. The thing here is that he is just resetting the statement which is the main problem.

Comment: Looking at the code it's obvious its not something the OP knows so a good answer would offer a complete fix. :)

Comment: This still has some issues. Only call `sqlite3_finalize` should only be called is `sqlite3_prepare_v2` succeeds and `sqlite3_close` should only be called if `sqlite3_open` succeeds.

Comment: Yep, let him do the rest of the error handling :) Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite3_prepare_v2` doesn't act the execution  You need to take a step into it

```
if(sqlite3_open([self.filePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK){
    NSString *sql = "DELETE  FROM reg";
    const char *query_st = [sql UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_st, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            // Deleted records,....
        }else{
             NSAssert1(0,@"Error when counting rows  %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: Why use a `while` loop? You only need to call `sqlite3_step` once for a `DELETE` query.

Comment: @rmaddy : just to ensure that its getting deleted row by row . && thanks for your inf

Comment: That's not how it works. The `DELETE` is done in one shot. The `while` loop will never execute more than once so it's pointless.

Comment: @rmaddy : Edited, I haven't gone in depth with that, so thanks a lot to point me in that way .

Comment: One other thing - the call to `sqlite3_finalize` should only be done if the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` succeeds. No need to finalize an unprepared statement.

Comment: @KumarKl please tell me wt is that queryfeedbackform in that wt actually i have to give there

Comment: if(sqlite3_open([self.filePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sql = "DELETE FROM reg";
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
      if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql,-1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
       {
       if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_Done) {
                // Deleted records,....

            }sqlite3_finalize(statement);
       }
     }
   }

Comment: @user3427551 : Check the edited one, hopefully fixes your problem .

Comment: @KumarKl can please update this one in your answer so then it will really help full

Comment: @KumarKl i used ur code  if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_Done) in this line its showing error like use of undeclared identifier SQLITE_Done. please tell how to resolve this

Comment: @rmaddy : Hopefully this is it . I can't find anymore faults with it . let me know, if you have any...Thank you for your suggestions, even your info fixes few of my issues too

Comment: @user3427551 Use **SQLITE_DONE** instead of small letters

Comment: @KumarKl Other than the formatting, it appears correct now. Though ideally, for the OP, error logging should be done on things that fail.

Comment: @rmaddy : finalised with all your inputs. Looks fine, Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
- (void) Delete_LoginData 
{
   // Open database first
   if(sqlite3_open([self.filePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
      // Sql query
      const char *sql = "DELETE FROM reg";
      // We are preparing the statement here
      if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql,-1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
      {
          // If that prepared statement is OK then we can execute that statement
          if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
          {
              NSLog(@" Records deleted successfully..");
          }
          else
          {
              NSLog(@" Opppsss..... Unable to delete records..");
          }
      }
      // Finalizing the statement
      sqlite3_finalize(statement);
      // Closing the database
      sqlite3_close(db);    
}
```

Hope this work for you...

Thank you...